# Encapsulating a log message

Tags: logging, log4net

I am looking for an efficient and generic design that encapsulates a log message.
I often find myself writing the same `logger.XXXFormat()` many times and I would like to encapsulate those messages into objects.
What i'm thinking is that I should use `logMessage.ToString()` to retrieve the log message from the object, but how do I encapsulate the formatting itself in a generic way so when given an object of type T it will extract the relevant data and format the message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you saying that you're often logging some formatted string built from the internals of an object instance? For example, you've got this `Address` type and you're always doing...

```
Log.InfoFormat("{0}; {1}, {2} {3}", address.Line1, address.City, address.State, address.Zip);
```

If so, then I have two recommendations.

#### [Mimeo](http://johncoder.com/Post/introducing-mimeo)

My friend, John Nelson (AKA John Coder), has a library for taking "stencils" and filling them in with object instances.

#### [FubuCore](http://lostechies.com/chadmyers/2011/06/10/cool-stuff-in-fubucore-no-9-stringification/) Stringifier and IDisplayFormatter

The geniuses of the [FubuMVC](http://fubumvc.com/) project have released their core projects separately. They deal with formatting and printing objects all the time. Check out their classes.

Comment: I'm cruising the log4net tag to gain huge rep :)